# How to access a specify property in a large JSON object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing my best to access a specific property of this large JSON object. The property seems to be there when I output the object with JSON.stringify but when I try to access the property through the code it says undefined. I'm not quite understanding why...? Maybe there's a hole in my knowledge base. Can you help me figure this out? It'd be much appreciated.

I get this JSON object when I outpu this.props.currentBuilding.apartments[0]

```
{
  "Id": 1341394,
  "PlutoId": 13684,
  "Borough": 1,
  "Block": "00837",
  "Lot": "0036",
  "Bin": 1015897,
  "HouseNo": "3",
  "HighHouseNo": "7",
  "StreetName": "WEST 35TH STREET",
  "ZipCode": 10001,
  "Buildings": 1,
  "Area": "7,406 SF",
  "Building": "Office: Designed Exclusively Banking",
  "LastTrade": "2001-11-19T05:00:00.000Z",
  "SalePrice": "0",
  "LastMortgage": "06/23/2015",
  "TotalDebt": 13660000,
  "Neighborhood": "Midtown South ",
  "YearBuilt": 1912,
  "BldgArea": 87301,
  "Address": "3 WEST 35TH STREET",
  "OriginalMortgage": 0,
  "NeighborhoodFull": "Midtown-Midtown South",
  "lender": "MANUFACTURERS TRADERS TRUST COMPANY",
  "LLCName": "ISTA WEST 35TH STREET LLC",
  "ParentCompanyName": null,
  "ParentCompanyAddress": null,
  "imageLink": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNPgpLZpTno_zpXU7NpquNu7Z1Y2QvHFiwQl7h4EY7c5mahU7HePpp_Jk",
  "image_url": ""
}
```

I want to access the address property in this object but I'm unable to do it unfortunately.

I'm looking to just output the address property in this object.

Comment: Don't provide images of code.  Provide the code.  Or in this case, copy the json from your console and put it in the question, formatted.

Comment: why are you stringifying in a render?

Comment: @HolyMoly they are  using it to debug

Comment: it's hard to tell what is going on here, but state is asynchronous and setting it in a render and trying to log at the same time is may be the issue.

Comment: else, try: `this.props.currentBuilding.apartments[0].Address`, based on what i can see in the screenshot.

Comment: `.Address` with a capital A, just like the JSON shows.

Comment: @HolyMoly Yeah I've tried that and I get undefined.

Comment: try taking the `setState` out of the render, and put it in a lifecycle event that happens _before_ the render, then try accessing the obj in the render. i think you may have a async thing going on. I have always liked this for a quick reference: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1):

The property names in JSON are case sensitive. The address property is **Address** (with a capital "A").

```
this.props.currentBuilding.apartments[0].Address
                                         ^
```